# Recuperar consulta de php mysql com ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Olá! gostaria de uma ajuda para saber como faço para recuperar dados da consulta php mysql e apresenta-lo na pagina que fez a solicitação via ajax, esse código no momento apresenta erro Cannot read property 'items' of null. gostaria de recupera os items separados pois o objetivo é criar novos elementos referente ao nome, mensagem etc. ex.: < div >+item.f+< / div >

Página php (faz a consulta)

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "chatheartbeat") { chatHeartbeat(); }
function chatHeartbeat() {
$sql = "select * from mensagens ";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$items = '';
$chatBoxes = array();
while ($chat = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$items .= <<<EOD
{
"s": "0",
"f": "{$chat['de']}",
"m": "{$chat['mensagem']}",
"i": "{$chat['img']}"
 },
EOD;
}
```

Index (chama a consulta par apresentar o resultado)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "asd.php?action=chatheartbeat",
  cache: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
alert(item.f)
});
}});
```

Comment: Você verificou se o php está retornando o esperado na requisição?

Comment: Sim usando load retorna normal os dados!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode transformar toda suas variaveiz em um json assim:

```
$sql = "select * from mensagens";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$chat = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo json_encode($chat,TRUE);
```

e para pegar a requisição em ajax usa o `getJson`

```
$.getJSON("seu_php.php", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(i, field){
      alert(field);
    });
});
```